# JavaScript check if value of an array object is value of other array object

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let companies = [
          {
            "countryCode": "DEU",
            "name": "Germany",
            "companyFunctions": [
              {
                "name": "E-Commerce",
                "companyName": "Company 1",
                "divisionIds": ["3"]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "countryCode": "FRA",
            "name": "France",
            "companyFunctions": [
              {
                "name": "Support Services",
                "companyName": "Company 2",
                "divisionIds": ["3", "4"]
              },
              {
                "name": "Procurement Support",
                "companyName": "Company 3",
                "divisionIds": ["1"]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

`let divisionIdsArr = [{ id: '1' }, { id: '2'}];`

I want to return a new array of companies, where the divisionId of the company matches with any `divisionIds`

So in this case only the second object, as shown below, would be returned, because it's the only object that has divisionId that is in `divisionIds`.

```
  {
        "countryCode": "FRA",
        "name": "France",
        "companyFunctions": [
          {
            "name": "Support Services",
            "companyName": "Company 2",
            "divisionIds": ["3", "4"]
          },
          {
            "name": "Procurement Support",
            "companyName": "Company 3",
            "divisionIds": ["1"]
          }
        ]
      }
```

How can I accomplish this?

I tried doing the following:

`companies.filter(c => c.companyFunctions.some(d => d.divisionIds.some(i => divisionIdsArr.includes(i))));`

However, this doesn't work because `divisionIdsArr` is an array of objects. So the `includes()` fails here.

`includes()` would work if the `divisionIdsArr` looked something like:
 `let divisionIdsArr = ["1", "2"];`

Comment: Updated the companies array object, there were a few typos, with property name.

Comment: `companies.filter(c => c.companyFunctions.some(cf => cf.divisionIds.some(id => divisionIds.map(di => di.id).includes(id))))` (I'm using .map() to go from an array of `{ id: x }` to an array of `x`)

Comment: Thank you can post that as answer.

`companies.filter(c => c.companyFunctions.some(cf => cf.divisionIds.some(a => divisionIdsArr.map(di => di.id).includes(a))))`

Comment: This question will not help anybody else and is therefore not really supposed to remain here; I still help via comment though, can't speak for other people

Comment: @OS pick an answer as the correct one

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution would be to change the division filter to simple id's instead of objects containing the id.

```
let divisionIds = ['1', '2'];
let result = companies.filter(c => c.companyFunctions.some(d => d.divisionIds.some(i => divisionIds.includes(i))));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` or [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert `[{ id: '1' }, { id: '2'}]` into `["1", "2"]`.

Using `Array.from`:

```
var result = companies.filter(c => c.companyFunctions.some(d => d.divisionIds.some(i => Array.from(divisionIds, x => x.id).includes(i))));
```

Also using `map` is something like described into comments, using `divisionIds.map(di => di.id)` instead of `Array.from`.

```js
companies.filter(c => c.companyFunctions.some(d => d.divisionIds.some(i => divisionIds.map(di => di.id).includes(i))));
```

So, clearer, your solution is to use:

```js
companies.filter(
  c => c.companyFunctions.some(
    d => d.divisionIds.some(
      i => YOUR_DESIRED_FUNCTION.includes(i))));
```

Where `YOUR_DESIRED_FUNCTION` can be:

```
Array.from(divisionIds, x => x.id)
```

or

```
divisionIds.map(di => di.id)
```

Both do the same, convert `[{ id: '1' }, { id: '2'}]` into `["1", "2"]`

Example here:

```js
let companies = [
  {
    "countryCode": "DEU",
    "name": "Germany",
    "companyFunctions": [{"name": "E-Commerce","companyName": "Company 1","divisionIds": ["3"]}]
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "FRA",
    "name": "France",
    "companyFunctions": [
      {"name": "Support Services","companyName": "Company 2","divisionIds": ["3", "4"]},
      {"name": "Procurement Support","companyName": "Company 3","divisionIds": ["1"]}
    ]
  }
]

let divisionIds = [{ id: '1' }, { id: '2'}];
var resultArray = companies.filter(
  c => c.companyFunctions.some(
    d => d.divisionIds.some(
      i => Array.from(divisionIds, x => x.id).includes(i))));
 var resultMap = companies.filter(
  c => c.companyFunctions.some(
    d => d.divisionIds.some(
      i => divisionIds.map(di => di.id).includes(i))));
console.log(resultArray)
console.log("---------------------------")
console.log(resultMap)
console.log("---------------------------")
console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArray) === JSON.stringify(resultMap))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/gpqLrv7c/13/

```
let companies = [
  {
    "countryCode": "DEU",
    "name": "Germany",
    "companyFunctions": [
      {
        "name": "E-Commerce",
        "companyName": "Company 1",
        "divisionIds": ["3"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "FRA",
    "name": "France",
    "companyFunctions": [
      {
        "name": "Support Services",
        "companyName": "Company 2",
        "divisionIds": ["3", "4"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Procurement Support",
        "companyName": "Company 3",
        "divisionIds": ["1"]
      }
    ]
  }
];

let divisionIdsArr = [{ id: '1' }, { id: '2'}];

let divisionIdsArValues = divisionIdsArr.map(a => a.id);

console.log(divisionIdsArValues);

let result = {};

companies.forEach( company => {
  company.companyFunctions.forEach( companyFunction => {
    // console.log(companyFunction);
    companyFunction.divisionIds.forEach( div => {
      // console.log(div);
      if (divisionIdsArValues.includes(div)) {
        console.log(company);
        result = company;
      }
    })
  })
});

console.log(result);
```